# Finding the maximum value for each row and extract column names

Tags: r, matrix, max

Say we have the following matrix,

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("X","Y","Z"), c("A","B","C")))
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1- Find the maximum value of each row. For this part, I'm doing the following,

```
df <- apply(X=x, MARGIN=1, FUN=max)
```

2- Then, I want to extract the column names of the maximum values and put them next to the values. Following the reproducible example, it would be "C" for the three rows.

Any assistance would be wonderful.

Comment: `apply(X = x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) colNames(x)[which.max(row)])`

Comment: What do you mean by putting them next to the values?

Comment: @tacoman it means to add the names as an extra column. Already answered by Jonas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` like

```
maxColumnNames <- apply(x,1,function(row) colnames(x)[which.max(row)])
```

Since you have a numeric matrix, you can't add the names as an extra column (it would become converted to a character-matrix).
You can choose a `data.frame` and do

```
resDf <- cbind(data.frame(x),data.frame(maxColumnNames = maxColumnNames))
```

resulting in

```
resDf
  A B C maxColumnNames
X 1 4 7              C
Y 2 5 8              C
Z 3 6 9              C
```